# How do you convert a operation and byte array to a hexadecimal string?

Tags: c#

I try to reverse that code.

```
var val = FormatFingerOp(BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String("EcE4Zodu3wRTBXntCdUvifj+/GggA3DnG6zEKRZGpcY=")));
```

FormatFingerOp do that thing:

```
var fp = "";
string[] keys = val.Split('-');
for (int i = 1; i <= keys.Length; i++)
{
    fp += keys[i - 1];
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        fp += " ";
}
```

I try that but it doestn work.
I try to reverse this steps like that:

```
string xsonuc = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= fp.Length; i++)
{
    xsonuc += fp[i - 1];
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        xsonuc += "-";
}


int NumberChars = val.Length;
byte[] ysonuc = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    ysonuc[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(val.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that in general case this is not reversible, `FormatFingerOp` will concatenate pairs of keys into one entry, i.e. `"one-three"` will become `"onethree"` so if you don't have any prior knowledge of key structure (like fixed length or something) - you can't reverse it.

As for your code - note that `FormatFingerOp` iterates array of strings, while it seems that your are trying to iterate the string itself (for starters you need to "reverse" new separator `" "`- so `fp.Split(" ")`).

**UPD**

Try the following:

```
var original = "EcE4Zodu3wRTBXntCdUvifj+/GggA3DnG6zEKRZGpcY=";
var val = BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(original));
var fp = "";
string[] keys = val.Split('-');
for (int i = 1; i <= keys.Length; i++)
{
    fp += keys[i - 1];
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        fp += " ";
}

// Reverse
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var pair in fp.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    sb.Append(new []{pair[0], pair[1]});
    sb.Append(new []{pair[2], pair[3]});
}

var toEncode = sb.ToString();
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromHexString(toEncode));

Console.WriteLine(base64String == original);
```

**UPD2**

Implementation which should be compatible with older .NET verions:

```cs
// Reverse
var split = fp.Split(new []{' '},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var bytes = new byte[split.Length * 2];
for (var index = 0; index < split.Length; index++)
{
    var pair = split[index];
    bytes[index * 2] = Convert.ToByte(pair.Substring(0, 2), 16);
    bytes[index * 2 + 1] = Convert.ToByte(pair.Substring(2, 2), 16);
}

var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(base64String == original);
```

Comment: its standard like that 11A1 3864 876E DZ04 5305 79ED 09D5 2F89 F8FE FC68 2003 70E7 1BAC C429 1646 A5C6

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir do you have original string?

Comment: "EcE4Zodu3wRTBXntCdUvifj+/GggA3DnG6zEKRZGpcY="

Comment: ı just want to "11A1 3864 876E DZ04 5305 79ED 09D5 2F89 F8FE FC68 2003 70E7 1BAC C429 1646 A5C6" to "EcE4Zodu3wRTBXntCdUvifj+/GggA3DnG6zEKRZGpcY="

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir there should be no `DZ04` in the string;

Comment: Thanks Guru, but i have error like cannot convert from string to char at foreach (var pair in fps.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) there

Comment: and convert doesnt contain definition for FromHexString

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251204/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-zeynep-aydemir).

Comment: Guru again thanks for your helping, but System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir - this is fully reproducible self-sufficient example - see it yourself ([@dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nYUjh0)).

Comment: ah it beacuse that StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries, thank you and thank you so much

Comment: guru what should i use instead of that StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir why do you need to use something instead of it?)

Comment: because it says argument2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char'

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir please check available overloads of `Split` and use appropriate one.

Comment: okey thank you Guru

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir JFY `var split = fp.Split(new []{' '},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`